# The flag link doesn't like being clicked on and disappears in the 10k queue

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools

I was strolling through the 10k queue today, and I happened upon a particular answer that was unworthy of existence. It was a disaster! Luckily, a noble "flag" link rushed up to save the day. I quickly clicked on it to flag as "Not an Answer," and it was all fine until then.

Suddenly, surprised by my click, the brave link ran away and disappeared!

[image: screenshot]

This only appears in the 10k queue, so apparently the flag links there are not trained in the art of mouse-cursor-seeing yet! Could we <s>put the links through a vigorous program of 10 cursors a day</s> fix this bug?

(Note that I first used aforementioned cursor to click on the triangle to expand the post, which did *not* run away in fright, indicating unequal training! Discrimination, I say!)

I used Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Windows 7 to conjure my cursor.

Comment: You shouldn't see the "share", "edit" and "flag" links in the first place. Maybe you have some rough userscript making them appear?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, edited post and deleted my other comments

Comment: Well, if you flag after clicking "flag or disagree" all is good. I think they should just hide those links when expanding.